# Selecting Rows Containing Each Unique Field Value & Sorting By Another Field With A Limit

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following fields/structure in my table:

```
(`map`, `authid`, `name`, `time`, `date`, `weapon`)
```

Every time a player completes a map in a game, this information is stored in a sql row in this table so long as for every `map` the `time` the player took to complete it is lower than any previously stored `time`. This means that there will only ever be one row per `map` for any given player (`authid`/`name`).

Now, on to my question. Being the SQL noob I am, I wish to figure out a query to run that will select the lowest 15 times *per map* (obviously if there are less than 15 entries per map all of them will be returned). I know I can create a query like the following in PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE map='". $map ."' ORDER BY time LIMIT 15;
```

But I need to end up with a multi-dimensional array (PHP) or object (JS) containing every unique `map` value to work with later in my code (and it needs to be sorted by time), ie.:

```
{"map1":[
    {"authid1":"val",
     "name1":"dude1",
     "time":"23.46",
     "date":"val",
     ...},
     {"authid1":"val",
     "name1":"dude2",
     "time":"42.33",
     "date":"val",
     ...},
     ...],
 "map2":[
    ...
    ...]
}
```

If I can't do this purely via SQL queries, then how could I utilize PHP or JS to finish my objective?

Comment: Search on `greatest-n-per-group` (Or here is an example article http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q1 = "SELECT map from tablename GROUP BY map ORDER BY map";
$r1 = $db->mysqli_query($q1);
while ($mapRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)) {
    $map = $mapRow['map'];
    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE map='". $map ."' ORDER BY time LIMIT 15";
    $r2 = $db->mysqli_query($q2);
    while ($dataRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r2)) {
        $map[] = $dataRow;
    }
}
```